# Memory optimized hashmap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We would like to implement a custom hashmap which has to be memory efficient. What I mean, is that we have upper bound of hashmap size e.g. 500 and a record size of 1 byte or even 3 bits. Our key set size is around 30k and we know only some part of it(500) will be put in it.

The best implementation would be hash-indexed table, but we cannot lose data if hashes crash and it's hard for me to figure out the way out, because we wouldn't like to put key in the memory.

The worst we can take is to add another byte per record.

Thanks for help. If it is undoable, that is also a helpful information.

Comment: Did you read about [collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) and can you state exactly what you find unclear?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I didn't know that wikipedia has such broad explanation of the topic. I will dig through it.

Comment: If you can live with False Positives, have a look on [bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: An alternative to collision resolution (as suggested above) is  [perfect hashing] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Perfect_hash_function). This can be done in advance (if keys are known) or by rehashing all entries when a new one is inserted (if it doesn't happen too often).